# Rails joins condition through child to get output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, associations

I have a Listing model which has one Property model attached to it. The Property is linked to a Location. What I'm trying to do is select all of the listings through the properties location which is passed in by an id. I've been working on this so far:

```
@location = Location.find(params[:id])

@listings = Listing.find(:all, :joins => [:property], :conditions => ["properties.location_id = ? ", @location])
```

What I would ideally like is something like "Find all listings where the property.location_id = @location"

This error is occuring, but I've read that its because I'm using mysql gem rather than the mysel2 gem (unfortunately I'm using a Windows machine)

> undefined method `explain' for #

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the whole location object to the parameter, but only the id is needed:

```
@location = Location.find(params[:id])

@listings = Listing.find(:all, 
                         :joins => [:property], 
                         :conditions => ["properties.location_id = ? ",
                                         @location.id])
```

Comment: The is probably a solution. I think Location serializes to something like #<Promotion:13214> which messes up slow query code in new rails